# Running a python script automatically after mysql starts on raspberry pi boot

Tags: python, mysql, linux, raspberry-pi, cron

I have written a python script that communicates with a mysql database. I made it start automaticalliy on boot by creating a launcher.sh file:

```
#!/bin/sh
#launcher.sh
cd /
cd home/pi/
sudo python ser.py
cd /
```

and adding

```
@reboot sh /home/pi/launcher.sh >/home/pi/logs/cronlog 2>&1
```

to the last line of the crontab by:

```
sudo crontab -e
```

when system reboots script tries to start working but it cannot connect to the mysql databse. When I start script by connecting with ssh everything works fine.

How can I start my script on boot automatically after all database services starts?

Comment: You can use the capabilities of your init system by defining dependencies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into a similar problem recently.

### A poor man's solution - sleep

By using sleep command you give MySQL server time to start (in most of Raspberry Pi use cases 5 seconds should be more than enough). It is not the most elegant solution but unless you are doing something that may affect MySQL server start time by a huge margin, this should do:

```
#!/bin/sh
#launcher.sh
sleep 5
cd /
cd home/pi/
sudo python ser.py
cd /
```

### A more advanced solution - script that checks if MySQL server has started

The basic idea is to attempt to connect to a local mysql server inside a loop and execute a query, exit, then evaluate the exit code. If the exit code is positive, run your part of the script, else retry.

```
mysql -e "desc mysql.user" -u <user> -p<password> >/dev/null
```

You can find a very nice script that does such a thing here:
http://forum.osmc.tv/showthread.php?tid=14823

Comment: 'wait' command did not work for me. I used 'sleep' insted. But the link you gave helped me a lot. Thanks

Comment: Whoops, I meant "sleep" in the first place. Will edit.

Comment: dead link. Please add the actual loop for mysql server start check.